# Como transformar valor de input em string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Como faço para transformar o valor de um input em uma string, inclusive se o usuário digitar tags HTML, com JavaScript ou jQuery.

```
<div class="val-input" contenteditable="true"></div>

$(function(){
    var val = $(".val-input").text();
});
```

Quero que o resultado saia assim se o usuário digitar uma tag HTML (as aspas representam a string)

```
"<p class="teste">Ola mundo!</p>"
```

E nao assim:

```
Ola mundo!
```

Comment: Se o usuário tiver acabado de digitar, o que você tem funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/05cpys6q/

Comment: Se eu digitar alguma tag HTML dentro do contenteditable ele só vai exibir o o valor de dentro da tag HTML

Comment: Retiras-te a aceitação da resposta. Algum erro na resposta? ou faltou algum detalhe?

Comment: Tentei de todas as formas utilizar a biblioteca he.js, mas em todas as vezes não funcionava, mesmo eu fazendo exatamente como no seu exemplo.

Comment: @DavidDamasceno juntei outra opção à resposta com exemplo também. Se quiseres podes fazer um jsFiddle que reproduza o teu problema com o `he.js` para eu dar uma olhada... ou então podes colocar aqui o código da tua página.

Comment: Ok, obrigado @Sergio , agora sim funcionou. Valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se percebo bem o teu problema o que queres é escapar as tags de HTML para poderes ver o código fonte desta maneira:

> <p class="teste">Ola mundo!</p>.

Para isso tens de transformar alguns dos simbolos dessa string de HTML nas suas entidades HTML correspondentes.

Sugiro usares uma biblioteca para isso como por exemplo o [he.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he)

O código ficaria assim:

```
$(function(){
    var val = $(".val-input").html(); // aqui tem de ser .html()
    var text = he.escape(val);        // <- esta é a linha que queres
    $("#mostrador").html(text);       // aqui tem de ser .html()
});
```

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/81w9bz2b/

---

## Opção para strings simples:

Se as strings forem simples podes usar [este código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034334/2256325):

```
 var entityMap = {
    "&": "&amp;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#39;',
    "/": '&#x2F;'
  };

  function escapeHtml(string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
      return entityMap[s];
    });
  }
```

O que o código faz é procurar na string por caracteres como `&<>"'\/` e subsitui-los na string pela sua representação visual em HTML, que está no objeto `entityMap`.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/mp05z61p/

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) ao invés de [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Em tradução livre o `.html()` :

> Obtém o conteúdo HTML do primeiro elemento no conjunto de elementos emparelhados ou define o conteúdo HTML de cada elemento correspondente.

### Sendo assim

você pode utilizar o código abaixo para obter o conteúdo *HTML* do *contenteditable*

```
$(function(){
    var val = $(".val-input").html();
});
```

Comment: Não não amigo, o que eu quero é transformar em texto (String) e não em html como o .html() faz.

Comment: se você não passar parâmetroe para o `.html()` ele vai te retornar uma streing com o *html* que éconteúdo da sua div, assim sendo a sua variavel `val` terá como valor uma streing.